# Which Android string to use for Settings Activity title

Tags: android, string, android-preferences

[image]

For my Settings activity, I want to use an Android-provided `String` for the title of my `Toolbar`, but after viewing Android's default `strings.xml` file, I noticed that 2 different strings are available, which both use the same name (i.e. "Settings").

**String A**

```
<!-- Application name displayed in notifications [CHAR LIMIT=60] -->
<string name="notification_app_name_settings">Settings</string>
```

**String B

```
<!-- label for item that launches settings in phone options dialog [CHAR LIMIT=15]-->
<string name="global_action_settings">Settings</string>
```

Which one of these strings should I be using for the Toolbar title of my Settings `Activity`?

Comment: Neither, insofar as neither are part of [the Android SDK](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/R.string).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest creating another string like

```
<string name="title_settings">Settings</string>
```

and use that one :)

Answer (score 0):

Do not use any system strings. That's is translators' nightmare later on. Create own strings instead and use that for whatever needed.